# Click button until val = true

Tags: javascript

So let's consider an input with id `phoneInput` that shuffles whatever you insert into the text field everytime you add something new so let's say we add the number `0728215523` it'll become a mess because it gets shuffled. Now we have a button `.shuffle` which shuffles again. How can i make the button get clicked until the number is the desired number I want. Here's what i tried but nothing happens and my browser crashes lol

```
do {
document.querySelector('.shuffle').click()
}
while(document.querySelector('#phoneInput').value !== '0728215523')
```

Comment: You mean from the browser? as in the user keeps clicking until the value is reached? or do you yourself need a code to automate the process in another website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's probably a much more efficient way to handle this problem if we knew the full implementation, but the below solution should provide a slightly more sane way to handle it...

```
var phoneCheck = setInterval(function (){
  if (String(document.querySelector('#phoneInput').value) === '0728215523') {
    clearInterval(phoneCheck);
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.shuffle').click();
  }
},250);
```

1. Clicks `.shuffle`
2. Waits 1/4 of a second (250 milliseconds)
3. Checks if `#phoneInput` value matches
4. Clicks again

Answer (score 1):

Use an event instead of the do while loop. You can use a keyup event on your input element.

```js
const phoneInput = document.getElementById('phoneInput');

const simClick = (e) => {
  if(e.target.value !== '0728215523') document.querySelector('.shuffle').click();
}

phoneInput.addEventListener('keyup', simClick)
```